# Reserved Error on access import into Reporting Services

Tags: ms-access, reporting-services

Error   14  An error occurred while the report CFPM001 - Portfolio Collateral Summary was being imported: Reserved Error        0   0

when I try to import access db into my visual studio reporting project. I have searched everywhere and nothing has been able to point me in the right direction. Is their anyway to debug this or find out what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a problem I'd not want to figure out.  I'd delete the report from access and recreate it by hand, why waste the time if all the others work?

Comment: that is legitimate answer, and is probably the route I will take but if their was a simpler solution I was hoping to get it!

Comment: Yeah, I understand the desire to fix every little thing - I have it too much, but these internal microsoft errors can be impossible to track down.  Even microsoft won't even know what they mean sometimes!